# Serializer field values based on request

Tags: django, django-haystack, drf-haystack

In Haystack, I have the following view set:

```py
class ArtistSearchViewSet(HaystackViewSet):
    index_models = (Artist,)
    serializer_class = ArtistSearchResultSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

This is the serializer:

```py
class ArtistSearchResultSerializer(HaystackSerializer):
    class Meta:
        index_classes = (ArtistIndex,)
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )
        search_fields = ("text",)
```

For each returned search result I want to add a boolean field that indicates whether the corresponding artist has been starred by the current user or not.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a field in your serializer that would be computed on the spot and returned in the response using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as such:

```py
class ArtistSearchResultSerializer(HaystackSerializer):
    starred = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        index_classes = (ArtistIndex,)
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "starred",
        )
        search_fields = ("text",)

    def get_starred(self, obj):
        # Your code here
        return field_value
```

The `def get_starred` method will be called every time the serializer is called, and will execute your code and return the field value you want to provide.